# Creating secure java application

Tags: java, windows, email, gmail

I have created a java mail application.
The time I want to send the mail successfully I need to ON the"allow less secure app" on my account.
That is my application is not secure.
***How can I create a secure java application so that there is no need to set anything "on" ????***

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to Google listing your app as "less secure", your app must use OAuth to authenticate the user to Gmail.

See this for more info:
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2017/05/04/what-are-less-secure-apps-in-google/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have tried this but i am facing problem in getting access token .I am using  the java code from here https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/wiki/OAuth2DotPyRunThrough#registering-an-application.